# Nothing being sent to server via URLConnection

Tags: java, ftp, urlconnection

So I've created a program that communicates with both a FTP and SQL server. I run my program on my Windows machine and everything is working fine. But when I run the program on my Ubuntu VM it is not working. My code is as follows:

```
try {

    URL  url = new URL(location);
    System.out.println("Created url");

    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

    System.out.println("Created URLConnection");

    urlc.setDoOutput(true);

    System.out.println("Set Output");

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlc.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Created OutputStreamWriter");

    System.out.println("Hello World.");

    out.write(Var.pressed);
    System.out.println("Wrote String");

    out.close();

    System.out.println("Closed OutputStreamWriter");

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The program creates a file on my FTP and then writes to it. The file is being created but it is empty. **No errors are ever thrown** my program prints the following

- Created url
- Created URLConnection
- Set Output

And then does nothing. It doesn't throw an error, it doesn't crash, it doesn't stop. The terminal is just left open. I also tried just running the .jar but nothing happens.

It seems as though the problem is created here:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlc.getOutputStream());
```

Why is nothing being written to the file? And what is wrong with my program if no errors are ever thrown?

Answer (score 0):

> It does throw an error,

From everything else, I think you meant to say it *doesn't* throw an error. My answer is assuming that anyway.

First there are many reasons for a program to hang or wait and not produce an error. Sometimes if you wait long enough a system threshold will be passed and it will timeout even though your program would be happy to wait forever. Other times the system isn't paying attention either. Error conditions are sort of like a courtesy.

I suggest you should try to make the connection with the Ubuntu ftp line command and compare the same with Windows. FTP protocol does some unusual things with ports. The connection opens on one port, but the data transfer connection is switched over to another port. Firewalls can be tripped up with the change of port and prevent the data transfer. This also has created clients that do "passive" versus "active" FTP.

Comment: I connected to FTP via terminal and got this i.gyazo.com/18b164a2cba5a95edce624ffc8e9f7c3.png

Comment: That is just to the point comparable to your program of "Created URLConnection". See if the **ls** command will work. If that works try **put** to write a file.

Comment: It said the Is command was invalid. Here is the result of the put command. i.gyazo.com/d43625b3bf9ba379177e8d6988aeb09b.png EDIT: The file is 0 bytes in size.

Comment: You can compare the results with the Windows system where your program works. The ls probably failed for the same reason the put did. Since (if) the Windows platform works with the same destination, it would most likely be the block is the firewall on your Ubuntu system.

Comment: @ZuberFowler A firewall would cause an exception of some kind.

Comment: iptables with DROP is not an "exception"

Comment: @ZuberFowler It causes a connection timeout exception at the client.

Comment: Whatever, if you're patient enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least get the response code, or the input stream. Otherwise not even a TCP connection is formed. And otherwise you have no idea whether the server accepted your input.

Your title was wildly inaccurate. Obviously you *are* creating the OutputStreamWriter. Your issue is that nothing is being sent. And the SQL tag was simply irrelevant.

Comment: Err, with getResponseCode()?

Comment: So I should change my URLConnection to an HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Yes, cast it to HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score -1):

Without an error message it is nearly impossible to figure out why it fails. A few suggestions, though.

First of all, try adding a `System.err.println("test")` This will prove that the output log will not only catch System.out AKA standard output stream, but also standard error stream. 
I asssume, that in after this fix, the `ex.printStackTrace()` will be visible.

Otherwise: You do not specify how your `location` String is filled. Are you sure, you have write access to that directory?
If location is `/tmp/foo/bar/myFile.txt`, make sure the directory /tmp/foo/bar/ exists (mkdir /tmp/foo/bar/) and that the file is accessible (touch /tmp/foo/bar/myFile.txt).

If both report no error AND the first suggestion would bring up no error, the program might really lock up and wait for something from the outside. Difficult to say what at the moment.

Comment: If he didn't have write access to the directory he wouldn't be able to create the file.